# Server 2008 blue screen after login - no desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, login, bsod

I came into work today to find that our Windows Server 2008 used as a terminal server for the Thin Clients was not loading the users desktops. What I have found out is that when I login via Remote Desktop, after applying user settings, it gets to the stage of 'Preaparing your desktop', but then the screen just goes blue.

I have tried rebooting several times with no luck, and logging in locally at the server with no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I do not think that it could be a virus attack as we run antivirus on the server with OpenDNS filtering. Yesterday a software restriction policy was set up to only allow programs in the following directories to run if that could be the problem, although it was working fine all day yesterday.

- C:\program files
- C:\programdata
- C:\windows

Thank you.

Jake

Comment: Do you need to add some other directories (eg D:\Program Files or C:\Program Files(x86))?   Also - check if you have any logon scripts defined which call an executable from a UNC somewhere?  I've seen logon script hold-ups cause this blank blue screen issue in Citrix farms.

Comment: Hi, no everything is on the C drive, and as it's a 32bit installation there is no additional 32bit folders. No logon scripts are set to run. When I sat locally at the server and pressed CTRL ALT DELETE, I was presented with this error: Log on process has failed to create the security options dialog. Could this be a fault with the logon service?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove that software restriction policy and try again. It's most probably the cause, I guess. (It's always the last thing you changed... :) )

Comment: Booting in safe mode loads explorer fine, but in normal mode the login doesn't load properly - just the blue screen, so it could be GPO related. However when I press CTRL ALT DELETE I get this error: The logon process has failed to create the security options dialog. So maybe it's a logon service issue?

Comment: Again, this could be a GPO restriction. Remove the GPO.

Comment: How can I go about removing the GPO object, as when I boot in safe mode the domain controller cannot be contacted, and when I boot normally I get the blue screen with no desktop etc. I've tried RSAT on Windows 7 but then I get this: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
Any ideas?

Comment: Software restriction policies are stored in the registry. I assume a computer GPO is used, try to delete this registry key in safe mode: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help - that has solved the problem. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. On the StackExchange network, you should select posts which solve your problem as "Answer".